# R Packages urca and aTSA yielding different values of the test statistic

Tags: cointegration, augmented-dickey-fuller

I am testing for the cointegration of 2 series in 2 ways: 1) by obtaining the residuals from the regression of one on the other and conducting an ADF test on the residuals (using package urca); and 2) by using the aTSA package to do the same. I expect the value of the test statistic from these 2 methods to be identical (critical values would be different), instead I get -7.08 with method 1 and -9.53 with method 2. Where I am going wrong with it?

```
set.seed(100)
X <- matrix(rnorm(200),100,2)
y <- 0.3*X[,1] + 1.2*X[,2] + rnorm(100)
x<-X[,1]
#run regression to get residuals
m<-lm(y~x)
resid<-m$residuals
#sample ADF test with 1 lag (not worried about excess serial correlation now)
u<-urca::ur.df(y=resid, type = "none",lags=1)
a<-aTSA::coint.test(y,x,nlag=1,output=F)
paste0("test statistic from urca:",round(u@teststat,2))
paste0("test statistic from aTSA:",round(a[1,2],2))
```

Comment: `aTSA::coint.test` counts the number of lags differently than `urca::ur.df`. To match, `nlag` in `aTSA::coint.test` should be 1 higher than `lags` in `urca::ur.df`. See the documentation of `aTSA::adf.test`, where it is made explicit that `nlag=1` corresponds to *no* lagged differences on the RHS, instead of having 1 such lag.

Comment: @ChrisHaug You are spot on. Thank you. Did you want to put this comment as an answer and I will mark the question as answered.